# how to send an email when creating a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that will send me an email every time it pings an IP address.
When I run the script I get and error saying

```
bash: sendmail: command not found
```

Here is my code

```
while true; do

    ping my_ip_address


    echo "some message" | sendmail -s "test" "test@test.com"
    sleep 20
done
```

and this is my sendmail.ini file

```
smtp_server=smtp.mailtrap.io
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=f1e1ea69338455
auth_password=97ce281bfdb99f
pop3_server=pop3.mailtrap.io
pop3_username=f1e1ea69338455
pop3_password=97ce281bfdb99f
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

I have my sendmail.ini saved in C:\sendmail\

Comment: What's not clear about the error message? This command doesn't exist, so you should install it first

Comment: I thought that's what I did. I went through this to see how to install it. https://websistent.com/using-sendmail-on-windows/

Comment: Then you should provide the full path to `sendmail.exe`, like `C:\sendmail\sendmail.exe` in the article

Comment: or add it to your `$PATH`.

Comment: @ForceBru - thanks that worked. Now to get it to send :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sendmail is not in your `$PATH`.

Try to either add directory with sendmail to your `$PATH` or use full path to sendmail.

Edit:
Also remove credentials from your question.

Comment: Removing credentials from the question does not matter. It stays in the question history 4ever.